# Identify and create a list of all the misspelled words in new column

Tags: python, spell-checking

I would like to apply SpellChecker function to identify all misspelled words in each sentence, then create a list of those misspelled words in a new dataframe column.

For example, Input:

| ColumnA |
| --- |
| I tried many times to iddentify misspelled words |
| I trried many timees to identtify misspelled words |
| I tried maany timees to identify missspelled words |

Desired Output:

| ColumnA | ColumnB |
| --- | --- |
| I tried many times to iddentify misspelled words | [{iddentify}, {misspelled}] |
| I trried many timees to identtify misspelled words | [{trried}, {timees}, {identtify}] |
| I tried maany timees to identify missspelled words | [{maany}, {timees}, {missspelled}] |

I have tried these code, but the result shows something like this (character-based checking instead of word-based checking):
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNKqH.png)

```
!pip install pyspellchecker
from spellchecker import SpellChecker
spell = SpellChecker()
df['ColumnB'] = [list(map((spell.unknown), word)) for word in df['ColumnA']]
df['ColumnB']
```

```
Requirement already satisfied: pyspellchecker in /opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages (0.7.1)
0    [{c}, {h}, {}, {}, {f}, { }, {m}, {}, {d}, {},...
1    [{c}, {d}, {c}, { }, {}, {p}, {d}, {}, {t}, { ...
2    [{w}, {h}, {}, {n}, { }, {w}, {}, {l}, {l}, { ...
Name: ColumnB, Length: 3, dtype: object
```

Comment: Have you tried `for word in df['ColumnA'].str.split()`?

Comment: your `list(map)` is effectively `[spell.unknown(letter) for letter in word]`. I don't think this is what you are meaning to do.